# Insert html-formatted text

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm having trouble inserting text with HTML formatting in the code below. where is it: 'insert the html here !!! "

the plugin is this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sensei-certificates/
I would like to format the certificate that is generated in pdf

I don’t know if I’m asking the right way, but it’s because I don’t understand that much.

Please help me :(

```
       $certificate_message = __( 'This is to certify that', 'sensei-certificates' ) . " \r\n\r\n" . $student_name . " \r\n\r\n" . __( 'insert the html here!!!!', 'sensei-certificates' ); // This is to certify that {{learner}} has completed the course
          if ( isset( $this->certificate_template_fields['certificate_message']['text'] ) && '' != $this->certificate_template_fields['certificate_message']['text'] ) {
```

Comment: Try to narrow down your code, please. With all due respect, nobody here is willing to read 500 lines of code to fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry.
I removed excerpts, I hope you can still understand me